# android debugging on remote device : logs not showing on the debugging console

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, logging

I'm new to Adnroid dev so please pardon me if this is a newbie question.

I'm debuging my android app on remote device and everything goes well except for the logs not showing on my debug console in IntelliJ/Adnroid Studio. I'm logging via android.util.Log API (ie Log.e or Log.i). However there are some logs showing : I assume that those are the generic Android API logs. And if my application crashes spectacularly I see nice stacktrace as well.

Is there somehting that I'm missing in my IDE conf? Is it configurable on logcat level?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with some below steps maybe that can help you

Option:1
Filter your log with `"No filter"` option

Option:2
Fire this command in terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb restart-server
```